# Running Vagrant & Symfony2 on Windows

Tags: windows, symfony, vagrant

Apologies if this is in the wrong area but I'm not sure where the question really belongs.

I have a working setup that uses Vagrant & puphpet & symfony 2.  It creates an apache, mysql, php, symfony stack as a local dev environment.  This deploys perfectly to any developers that are using mac's.

I am trying to get it working on a windows based machine and it doesn't work.

I have tried normalizing line endings but shell scripts are not working correctly and the apache server never responds to the opening of the app_dev.php.

I could use some help trying to debug whats gone wrong.

I have a succesful VM
I have a box that responds to the ping
I have a successful composer install
I have a successful run of puphpet altough one of the OS detect.sh does object to \r as part of the output and the exec-once script i have to type the commands by hand to get them to work
I have a running apache server and mysql server
I have a successful doctrine:database:create and schema:create.

Any Ideas what I should check next.

Comment: Show your scripts and Vagrantfile. It is hard to tell what goes wrong when vagrant tries to provision your vm.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a problem with NFS on Windows.  NFS was so slow everything timed out.  We switched to rsync for windows users and apart from some permissions problems it largely works ok